# Recommended best practice for multi threaded task in winforms application at newbie level

Tags: .net, vb.net, multithreading, winforms

I am currently trying to update a very simple winforms application to use a multi threaded solution. But I lack the background knowledge of how best to go about it.

I've seen a lot of solutions revolving around lists of background workers or using Tasks or using Thread directly or even Parallel.ForEach loops. The more I read, the more confused I become about what might be the best solution.

To put my experience into context, I'm still at the stage of writing single threaded solutions that leave the UI inaccessible while my programs are doing the heavy lifting. I'm aware enough to know this isn't ideal and things like backgroundworkers should be used, but inexperienced enough to have not implemented a better solution yet.

In this case specifically, I am loading a database of names and addresses into memory and attempting to find duplicates. I have two loops, both looping through the same list of addresses that I think of as the "left loop" and "right loop". Item 1 of the left loop is compared with each item of the right loop using fuzzy string matching. Anything within tolerance (and not the same record) is added to a DataGridView table as a possible match. Loop through the "right" loop trying find matches, then repeat for each "left" loop value.

Except it could clearly be done better. At the very least it could be a background worker. But ideally multiple background workers. I figure each "thread" could be loop through the "right" list for a single "left" list item.

I have a number of requirements here.

- I need to be able to pass a parameter to the thread (the left list
  data).
- I need potential matches to be added to a UI component. There
  could be multiple matches in the "right" list for a single "left"
  list item.
- Being able to cancel the background threading would be nice, but not essential.
- If I had 120,000 names and addresses, I'd rather not start 120,000
  simultaneous threads.

Ideally, I'd prefer a solution that scales with hardware (Starting 50 largely identical threads on a dual core machine seems counter-intuitive and hard-coding 16 identical background workers seems sloppy).

The most straight forward solution (to me right now) looks like a list of background workers. Except I'm not sure how to code the DoWork, RunWorkerCompleted or ProgressedChange functions to cope with multiple workers rather than being tied to a single one.

I'd welcome feedback about my matching strategy, but I'm mainly looking to be pointed in the right direction to allow this program to finish in less than 3 weeks having only used 6% of my CPU the whole time.
Specific practical answers especially welcome.

Answer (score -1):

In most of the cases :

1. **BackgroundWorker** for an unique task that runs in the background with some interactions with the UI.
2. **Thread** when you have a long-term task which must be constantly running in the background.

In your case, a background worker will be nice.

```
private readonly BackgroundWorker myWk = new BackgroundWorker();
```

Setup your worker :

```
wkNoGen.DoWork += ActionmyWk;
wkNoGen.RunWorkerCompleted += EndmyWk;
wkNoGen.ProgressChanged += ProgressmyWk;
wkNoGen.WorkerReportsProgress = true;
wkNoGen.WorkerSupportsCancellation = true;
```

Start the worker :

```
// for exemple with a list of string : List<string> myStrings
 myWk.RunWorkerAsync(argument: myStrings);
```

Your worker actions :

```
private void ActionmyWk (object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    // If you have to get an object
    List<string> myStrings = (e.Argument as List<string>);

    // Send update progress
    myWk.ReportProgress(0, $"Worker is starting.");

    // Your work
    foreach (string aString in myStrings)
    {
        // End the worker if cancellation is pending
        if (myWk.CancellationPending) { e.Cancel = true; return; }

        // Do work

    }

}
```

Action when your worker send an update :

```
private void ProgressmyWk (object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
{
    // Use e.UserState to get information from your worker
    var item = e.UserState as string;
    if (item != null)
    {
        Messagebox.Show("Worker update : " + item;
    }
        // Use e.ProgressPercentage if you need to display it
}
```

Action when your worker end :

```
private void EndmyWk (object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Cancelled) { MessageBox.Show("Manual ending."; }
    else { MessageBox.Show("Normal ending."; }
}
```

How to send the cancellation :

```
myWk.CancelAsync();
```

You can only send 1 parameter (argument) when you start your worker it can be whatever you want. So you can use a struct or an objet that contains everything you need.
This is the same for the e.UserState.

Comment: If I am following that correctly, it focuses on a single background worker solving a single task - but allowing the UI to remain responsive. That is definitely useful information for some of my other programs, thanks for explaining it so comprehensively.
But how would I scale that up to allow multiple background workers? I have approx 120,000 address to match against themselves. My hope is to process 24 simultaneously (on my 12 core CPU) until all 120,000 have been compared. Although I accept perhaps my expectations are wrong.

Comment: You are right, background worker works well but it's a "single thread". If you want to use so many threads at the same time, maybe you should look for **tasks** or **thread pool**. But I'm not knowledgeable enough to explain it to you.